# How does $a^2-4b(a-b)$ simplify to $(a-2b)^2$?

Tags: arithmetic

Please explain, step by step. I'm really stuck with this.

Comment: In general it will not simplify the way you are suggesting

Comment: it doesn't simplify to that. do you start with $a^2$ or $2^2$

Comment: Yes, I made mistake,  a^2 is what I intended to type. Sorry about the tag, I'm new so the site doesn't let me use more appropriate tags for some reason..

Comment: Have you tried to expand both expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a^2-4b(a-b)$

$= a^2-4ab+4b^2$

$ = (a-2b)^2$

Comment: Sorry, 2^2 was mean to be a^2

Comment: Edited the answer as for the change.